# Very high loss in TensorFlowJS

Tags: angular, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow.js, loss

I'm following this tuto [Time Series Forecasting with TensorFlow.js](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-tensorflow-js-1efd48ff2201) ; I'm new in data science and TensorflowJS.

I think I have made an error but I can't find where.
I am at the step for training model, and I have very high loss, from 651878.125 to 411721.
I tried to increase the number of epochs, it continues to decrease but still high (aroung 125000.000).
Is that normal? How do I need to change for getting a result nearest to 0.0001?

My variables are: WINDOW_SIZE: number = 50, TRAINING_SIZE: number = 0.85; //= 70%, EPOCHS: number = 25, LEARNING_RATE: number = 0.01, N_LAYERS: number = 4.

Prices are from 3800$ to 9500$, I have between 1000 and 2000 records, in an array of objects {date, value} named stockPrices = Array<{date, value}> ({date, value} is a class named 'Data').

Thanks for your help.

My SMA function:

```
computeSMA(stockPrices:Array<Data>, window_size:number): Promise<Array<any>> {
    let r_avgs = [], prices = [], avg_prev = 0;
    //Get only prices, witout dates:
    for (let i = 0; i < stockPrices.length; i++) {
      prices.push(stockPrices[i].value);
    }
    //SMA calculation on window_size:
    for (let i = 0; i <= prices.length - window_size; i++){
      let curr_avg = 0, t = i + window_size;
      for (let k = i; k < t && k <= prices.length; k++){
        curr_avg = curr_avg + prices[k];
      }
      curr_avg = curr_avg / window_size;
      r_avgs.push({ 
        set: prices.slice(i, i + window_size), 
        avg: curr_avg
      });
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (r_avgs.length > 0) {
        resolve(r_avgs);
      } else {
        reject([]);
      }
    });
  }
```

The call to training model:

```
  //After calling computeSMA, I separate inputs (arrays of window_size values) from outputs (SMA) :
  for (let i = 0; i < smaValues.length; i++) {
    this.inputs.push(smaValues[i]['set']);
    this.outputs.push(smaValues[i]['avg']);
    console.log(smaValues[i]['avg']);
  }
  //inputsToTrain and outputsToTrain = this.WINDOW_SIZE % of data for training the model.
  this.inputsToTrain = this.inputs.slice(0, Math.floor(this.TRAINING_SIZE * this.inputs.length));
  this.outputsToTrain = this.outputs.slice(0, Math.floor(this.TRAINING_SIZE * this.outputs.length));
  //inputsToValidate or outputsToValidate = (1 - this.WINDOW_SIZE) % of data for validating the model.
  this.inputsToValidate = this.inputs.slice(Math.floor(this.TRAINING_SIZE * this.inputs.length), this.inputs.length);
  this.outputsToValidate = this.outputs.slice(Math.floor(this.TRAINING_SIZE * this.outputs.length), this.outputs.length);
  //Train the model.
  this.trainModel(this.inputsToTrain, this.outputsToTrain, this.WINDOW_SIZE, this.EPOCHS, this.LEARNING_RATE, this.N_LAYERS, (epoch, log) => {
    console.log(`${'EPOCH '}${epoch + 1}${' / '}${this.EPOCHS}${' ; Loss = '}${log.loss}`);
  });
```

The training model function:

```
async trainModel(X, Y, window_size, n_epochs, learning_rate, n_layers, callback){

    //Entraîne le modèle.

    const input_layer_shape  = window_size;
    const input_layer_neurons = 100;

    const rnn_input_layer_features = 10;
    const rnn_input_layer_timesteps = input_layer_neurons / rnn_input_layer_features;

    const rnn_input_shape  = [rnn_input_layer_features, rnn_input_layer_timesteps];
    const rnn_output_neurons = 20;

    const rnn_batch_size = window_size;

    const output_layer_shape = rnn_output_neurons;
    const output_layer_neurons = 1;

    const model = tf.sequential();

    const xs = tf.tensor2d(X, [X.length, X[0].length]).div(tf.scalar(10));
    const ys = tf.tensor2d(Y, [Y.length, 1]).reshape([Y.length, 1]).div(tf.scalar(10));

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: input_layer_neurons, inputShape: [input_layer_shape]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: rnn_input_shape}));

    let lstm_cells = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < n_layers; index++) {
        lstm_cells.push(tf.layers.lstmCell({units: rnn_output_neurons}));
    }

    model.add(tf.layers.rnn({
      cell: lstm_cells,
      inputShape: rnn_input_shape,
      returnSequences: false
    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: output_layer_neurons, inputShape: [output_layer_shape]}));

    model.compile({
      optimizer: tf.train.adam(learning_rate),
      loss: 'meanSquaredError'
    });

    const hist = await model.fit(xs, ys,
      { batchSize: rnn_batch_size, epochs: n_epochs, callbacks: {
        onEpochEnd: async (epoch, log) => {
          callback(epoch, log);
        }
      }
    });

    return { model: model, stats: hist };
  }
```

Comment: Loss is different from accuracy... you might be expecting to see accuracy instead of loss?

Also, It really depends on a lot of things. I'd consider changing the size / shape of your network to better, play with the hyper parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to get accuracy using let accuracy = await model.evaluate(xs, ys, {batchSize: 64}); console.log(accuracy.toString()); and it retruns: Tensor 596385.875, Tensor 0. Maybe I have a mistake for getting accuracy?

Comment: hmm I'll have a think about it but to be honest I'm using the Python library at the moment so I'm not entirely sure (although I am confident with JS I've not used Tensorflow.JS yet). I'll be looking at it soon though.

Comment: Accuracy is 0!
Why? How is it possible? What is wrong in my trainModel function or SMA function?